# Autofac: how do I pass a reference to the component being resolved to one of its dependents?

Tags: ioc-container, autofac

With the following:

```
public class AClass
{
  public ADependent Dependent { get; set; }
}
public class ADependent
{
  public ADependent(AClass ownerValue) {}
}
```

with the following registrations...

```
builder.RegisterType<AClass>().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<ADependent>().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerDependency();
```

When I resolve an AClass, how do I make sure that 'ownerValue' is the instance of AClass being resolved, and not another instance? Thx

**FOLLOW ON**

The example above doesn't really catch the problem properly, which is how to wire up ADependent when registering when scanning... for example

```
public class AClass : IAClass
{
  public IADependent Dependent { get; set; }
}
public class ADependent : IADependent
{
  public ADependent(IAClass ownerValue) {}
}

// registrations...

  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .AssignableTo<IAClass>()
    .As<IAClass>()
    .InstancePerDependency()
    .PropertiesAutowired();

  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .AssignableTo<IADependent>()
    .As<IADependent>()
    .InstancePerDependency()
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```

The function I am looking for really is another relationship type like

```
public class ADependent : IADependent
{
  public ADependent(OwnedBy<IAClass> ownerValue) {}
}
```

The OwnedBy indicates that ownerValue is the instance that caused ADependent to created.  Does something like this make sense?  It would certainly make wiring up UI components a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

To extend Steven's approach, you can even `Resolve()` the second class, passing the first instance as a parameter:

```
builder.RegisterType<ADependent>();
builder.Register<AClass>(c =>
{
   var a = new AClass();
   a.Dependent = c.Resolve<ADependent>(TypedParameter.From(a));
   return a;
});
```

Comment: Thx.  But the reason I don't like this is that it loses the autowiring, which to me is most of the benefit of IOC.  Also, what would I do when scanning assemblies?  I've edited my question to make the example closer to me real problem.

Comment: Hi Tom - you can build this approach into your scanning configuration if you feel the need - just do the assignment of the property in the `OnActivating()` event, passing the instance as a parameter. A bit more code, and you need to figure out how to mark the property (maybe with a marker type) rather than the ctor param. Cheers, Nick.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a lambda to do the trick:

```
builder.Register<AClass>(_ =>
{
    var a = new AClass();
    a.Dependent = new ADependent(a);
    return a;
});
```

Comment: Agreed.  But how do I do this when scanning?  I've edited my question further.